# Delete QTreeWidgetItem in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

I'm finding it frustratingly hard to find a simple way to delete my selected `QTreeWidgetItem`.

My patchwork method involves setting the tree's current selection to `current` and then:

```
if current.parent() is not None:
   current.parent().removeChild(current)
else:
   self.viewer.takeTopLevelItem(self.viewer.indexOfTopLevelItem(current))
```

It's not horrible, but isn't there a command that straight up just removes the item?

Comment: I believe yours is the correct way. In C++ you could simply delete the item, therefore invoking its destructor, and that will remove the item from the widget. But I don't think there is a direct way to do that from Python.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `QTreeWidget` class has an [`invisibleRootItem()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtreewidget.html#invisibleRootItem) function which allows for a somewhat neater approach:

```
root = tree.invisibleRootItem()
for item in tree.selectedItems():
    (item.parent() or root).removeChild(item)
```

Answer (score 10):

PyQt4 uses sip to generate the python bindings for Qt classes, so you can delete the C++ object explicitly through [the sip python API](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#module-sip):

```
import sip
...
sip.delete(current)
```

The binding generator for PySide, shiboken, has [a similar module](http://www.pyside.org/docs/shiboken/shibokenmodule.html).

Comment: I will use this in the future, but I went with the other answer. Thanks though!

Comment: This was short and sweet answer. Thanks!