# How to delete QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Several webpages say that `QTreeWidgetItem` can be deleted by deleting or `QTreeWidget.clear`ing. But my code sample below doesn't seem to do so. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem # Result was the same with `PySide`
import time

class TreeWidgetItemChild(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeWidgetItemChild, self).__init__()
        print 'TreeWidgetItemChild init'

    def __del__(self):
        print 'TreeWidgetItemChild del'

def test_QTree_clear_children():
    tree = QTreeWidget()
    tree.setHeaderLabel('funksoul')
    i = TreeWidgetItemChild()    
    tree.addTopLevelItem(i)    
    print 'Before clearing'
    #tree.clear()                  # Didn't call destructor (__del__)
    #tree.removeItemWidget (i, 0)  # Didn't call destructor
    #i.__del__()                   # Called destructor but it's called again afterward
    del i                          # Didn't call destructor
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'After clearing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test_QTree_clear_children()
```

Printed as:

```
TreeWidgetItemChild init
Before clearing
After clearing
TreeWidgetItemChild del
```

Looks to me `TreeWidgetItemChild` gets deleted upon the termination of process, not by any of my deletion actions.

Comment: Not sure about python, but in C++ deleting a QListWidgetItem will make it remove itself from the list, too (the destructor does this).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python is different from C++ in the sense of memory management/deleting objects. Python has a garbage collector (GC) that manages destroying of the objects automatically. That occurs when the reference count of an object reaches zero.

`del i` only means 'decrement the reference count by one'. It never results in a direct call to `__del__`. `__del__` of an object is only called when reference count reaches to zero and is about to be garbage collected. (Although this is true for CPython, it's not guaranteed for every implementation. It depends on the GC implementation. So you should not rely on `__del__` at all)

Keeping story short, the call time of `__del__` is ambiguous. You should never call `__del__` (or any other `__foo__` special methods) directly. In fact, for the reasons above you should rather avoid the use of `__del__` at all (usually).

Apart from that, there is another issue.

```
tree.removeItemWidget(i, 0)
```

This does not remove an item from `QTreeWidget`. As the name suggests, it removes a *widget* from an item, not the `QTreeWidgetItem`. It's counterpart to the `setItemWidget` method, not the `addTopLevelItem` method.

If you need to remove a specific item from the tree, you should use `takeTopLevelItem`.

```
tree.takeTopLevelItem(tree.indexOfTopLevelItem(i))
```

`tree.clear()` is fine. It will remove every top level item from the tree.

Comment: Based on some testing I did with python garbage collection of Qt object I found that python couldn't collect them in spite it having zero referees.

Comment: @hus787: Oh? How did you test it?

Comment: so I developed this small GUI app(Qt based) and instantiated it by calling a python function which also returned its reference name(`plugins.foo.bar.some_random_string` whose parent is the main maya window). Then without closing/hiding the window, calling `del plugins` or `del plugins.foo.bar.some_random_string`, and thereafter even calling `gc.collect`, did not cause the window to disappear i.e. get destroyed by python's garbage collection.
`plugins` and `foo` are packages, `bar` is a module and `some_random_string` is the window object itself.

Comment: @hus787: Huh? Why would python garbage collect that window? If it has a parent, then it has a reference. That parent keeps a reference. It doesn't matter whether there are explicit names pointing to it or not. Its reference count is not zero.

Comment: First of all place forgive my ignorance, I am new to the garbage collection phenomenon. So according to your statement should I expect to find that window in `gc.garbage` and consequently get its referrer through `gc.get_referrers`? Or would you suggest posting a new question about this?

Comment: @hus787: No, it's not 'unreachable'. You can reach it through the parent (e.g. `parent_object.children()`). And if you check the `gc.get_referrers` before you delete, in addition to the name you given, you'll see the parent is there too.

Comment: @hus787: I hope this clears the confusion: http://bpaste.net/show/tiHqOiU2NNJ87gpQIUnS/ There is a `QPushButton` that creates two `QDialog`s and stores them as attributes. One dialog is parentless, one has the `QPushButton` as parent. Clicking on the button will remove the attributes (i.e. deleting those references). Parentless dialog will be then garbage collected because it has no other references. Parented one stays open because the button is still there and it keeps a reference. Even though `self.window` is no more available.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You were right the main window(parent) was in fact listed in `gc.get_referrers`, although without any explicit name, hence stopping the widget/window from getting collected. Thank-you once again.

Comment: Ahh, so the method is `takeTopLevelItem()`. I wonder, what good is a reference when the API is named shit.

Answer (score 5):

As an epilogue to [Avaris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065056/2809027)' [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065056/2809027), let's flog an even *more* general-purpose approach applicable to all widgets and widget items (rather than merely top-level tree widget items). Is this supposed Shangri-La too good to be true?

To quoth the Mario: *"Waaaa! Let's-a-go!"*

### Here We-A-Go

Specifically, if your project leverages:

- PySide2, import the `shiboken2` module and pass each tree widget item to be deleted to the `shiboken2.delete()` function ala:

  ```
  # Well, isn't that nice. Thanks, Qt Company.
  from PySide2 import shiboken2

  # Add this item to this tree.
  tree = QTreeWidget()
  item = TreeWidgetItemChild()
  tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

  # Remove this item from this tree. We're done here, folks.
  shiboken2.delete(item)
  ```
- PyQt5, import the `sip` module and pass each tree widget item to be deleted to the `sip.delete()` function ala:

  ```
  # Well, isn't that not-quite-so-nice. You are now required to import any
  # arbitrary PyQt5 submodule *BEFORE* importing "sip". Hidden side effects are
  # shameful, of course, but we don't make the rules. We only enforce them. For
  # detailed discussion, see:
  #
  #     http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-11
  #
  # If your project requires PyQt5 >= 5.11, the following compatibility hack may
  # be safely reduced to the following one-liner:
  #
  #     from PyQt5 import sip
  from PyQt5 import QtCore
  import sip

  # Add this item to this tree.
  tree = QTreeWidget()
  item = TreeWidgetItemChild()
  tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

  # Remove this item from this tree.
  sip.delete(item)
  ```

### Nothing Could Possibly Go Wrong

Yes, this behaves as expected under all platforms and (PyQt5|PySide2) releases.  The Python-specific `sip.delete()` and `shiboken2.delete()` methods are high-level wrappers around the underlying C++ `delete` operator – and operate exactly identically. In the case of `QTreeWidgetItem` instances, this reproduces the C++ behaviour of immediately removing the passed item from its parent tree.

Yes, it is both glorious and sketchy. Thanks to [alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm)'s [relevant answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135379/2809027) for the motivational impetus behind this overwrought answer. <sup>*Glory be to [alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm).*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

By calling `del i` you are just deleting the reference not the actual C++ Object(*referent*) it refers to, not the object itself.

Change your `TreeWidgetItemChild.__del__` function to:

```
def __del__(self):
    treeWidget = self.treeWidget()
    #removing the QTreeItemWidget object
    treeWidget.takeTopLevelItem(treeWidget.indexOfTopLevelItem(self))
    print 'TreeWidgetItemChild del'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing tree items (i.e., tree nodes) with the widgets that a given item can contain.

The following example creates a `QTreeWidget` and adds two items to it: a top level item and a nested one. Removing the comments you can see how both of them are removed from the tree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree)
        self.tree.setHeaderLabel('funksoul')
        i = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree, ['top level'])   
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(i)
        j = QTreeWidgetItem(i ,['nested level'])
        #i.takeChild(0)
        #self.tree.takeTopLevelItem(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MyMainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For removing both types of items from the tree you need the items index. If you have a reference to the item you want to remove you can get the corresponding index with the `indexOfTopLevelItem` and `indexOfChild` functions.