# How to delete custom defined widget classes in pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt, sip, pyside2, shiboken2

I am migrating a project from python27 to python37 so that I could switch from using PyQt to PySide. When refactoring my code, I am now unable to delete instances of my custom class that inherits from the QTreeWidgetItem

```
class CustomTreeItem(qtwidget.QTreeWidgetItem):
```

Originally, I was just doing `sip.delete(CustomTreeItem object)`. However, after the migration I tried doing the same thing with `shiboken2.delete(CustomTreeItem object)` and received the error

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Thinking that the error was related to shiboken2, I tried other ways of deleting

```
assm_tree_widget.clear()
```

and

```
selections = assm_tree_widget.selectedItems()
for item in selections:
    index = assm_tree_widget.indexOfTopLevelItem(item)
    assm_tree_widget.takeTopLevelItem(index)
```

Both of these throw similar exit codes.

Comment: It's normally not required to call `sip.delete`, why are you using it?

Comment: I didn't write the py27 code, just migrating. What would be the proper way to delete an instance of a QTreeWidgetItem? `shiboken2.delete` works fine on normal QTreeWidgetItem objects but breaks on my custom class. I tried the other alternatives I listed just to see if I could even delete the CustomTreeItem but those didn't even seem to work (not sure if they utilize shiboken under the hood).

Comment: If you're going to clear the whole tree widget with `clear()`, you don't need to delete anything, as Qt will take care of it (and python's garbage collector too).

Comment: I was just using `clear()` as an experiment to see if I could delete something in the tree without a direct shiboken call. It is not the intended functionality I want. However, it yields similar errors. Perhaps there is something wrong with my CustomTreeItem after the py37 migration? Its behavior seems correct to me which is why I'm asking about the inherited class.

Comment: I was specifically looking at this method for deleting TreeWidgetItems here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52675468/16262261

Comment: @RemusWong please provide a [mre]

Comment: If you want to remove an item from a QTreeWidget, use `takeTopLevelItem()` if it's a top level, otherwise `removeChild(item)` on the parent (including the `invisibleRootItem()`, which allows removing top level items too). If there's no other reference on the item, then it will be automatically deleted. It could be useful to know if there's a specific reason for trying to use `del`, and a MRE would help as already requested.

Comment: Ok I seem to have found he problem. There isn't anything inherently wrong with deleting a custom defined class but problems will occur if you mix `shiboken2.delete` calls with methods from the QTreeWidget that remove items that aren't native to PySide2. This is understandable behavior as for why I was getting memory access related errors. So, the solution was to just replace all my `shiboken.delete()` with standard `takeTopLevelItem()` methods.